# Enumerating all connected graphs with 9 vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

The version of my Mathematica is 10. I generate a connected graph with 9 vertices, but find that it is not included in Mathematica.

```
adjm = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 
  1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
  1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}};
g1 = AdjacencyGraph[adjm];
(*generate the graph g1*)
ori2 = GraphData[9];
set2 = GraphData[#] & /@ ori2;
set3 = Select[set2, ConnectedGraphQ[#] == True &];
IsomorphicGraphQ[g1, #] & /@ (set3)
(*generate all the graphs with 9 vertices, select the connected ones and check if g1 is there*)
```

The output is a list of `False`.

If I have missed something. Then the question is how to get the database of all connected graphs with 9 vertices?

Comment: Very important for all such questions: what precise version of Mathematica are you using, on what operating system?

Comment: OK, I looked at your code.  I cannot run it because at the moment I do not have access to a fast enough internet connection to be able to download all the graph data ... However, you seem to be assuming that `GraphData[9]` will return *all* possible graphs on 9 vertices.  I do not see why this should be so.  It is just a non-exhaustive graph database, don't assume it contains everything.

Comment: Actually there seem to be [no less than 274668](https://oeis.org/A000088) unlabelled graphs on 9 vertices ... which is much more than what the database can be expected to contain.  **Voting to close since this question is due to a simple misunderstanding.**

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! I update the question.

Comment: There is no such database built into Mathematica, so for a pre-made database you'd have to look elsewhere.  Generating all *unlabelled* graphs on 9 vertices and making sure there are no duplicates in the list is going to be hard and definitely impossible using a *naive* approach of simply using `IsomorphicGraphQ` to filter duplicates.  Not to say it's impossible with smarter methods (it probably is), but how to do it seems hard enough that I'd say it's a math question first, and a Mathematica question only once you have a strategy in mind ...

Comment: @Thanks again! I know it's hard also.

Comment: I found [this](http://gfredericks.com/sandbox/graphs).  It goes up to 9 vertices.  I do not know if it is exhaustive, it would be interesting to find out, and especially to have a full list.  Perhaps you can try contacting the author of that site?

Comment: Got it *finally*!   I knew I've seen this before.  Here's the full list: http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html  Very likely also used by the previous site I linked.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks so much! You're so kindly. I generate the graph6 format of `g1`, which is ` HhcWJEA`. But I do not find ` HhcWJEA` on the above link.

Comment: OK, I may take a look tomorrow, to tired now ...

Comment: Closers: Please wait

Comment: @EdenHarder I believe the Graph6 representation of a graph depends on the ordering of the vertices and, as such, is not unique so there's no reason to expect "HhcWJEA" to be on that list.  Presumably, one of the automorphisms of your graph leads to your g6 code.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a recursive way to get them all: (slow due to the use of `IsomorphicGraphQ` inside `DeleteDuplicates`, if anybody knows how to do it faster, please comment).
Much faster now thanks to @MarkMcClure's clever improvement.

**Edit**

Improved again by 40% prefiltering the added rows using the automorphisms of the n-1 graph:

```
<< Combinatorica`
filtPerms[skel_, rows_] := Module[{perms, gathered},
  perms = FindPermutation /@ (Automorphisms@FromAdjacencyMatrix@skel);
  gathered = GatherBy[rows, Tr@# &];
  Flatten[ DeleteDuplicates[#, MemberQ[System`Permute[#1, PermutationGroup[perms]], #2] &] & /@
                                                                                    gathered, 1]
  ]
getConnG[2] = {{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}};
getConnG[n_] := getConnG[n] = 
  Module[{skels, rows, adjk, gathered}, 
   skels = ArrayPad[#, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}] & /@ getConnG[n - 1];
   rows = Rest@Tuples[Join[{{0}}, Array[{0, 1} &, n - 1]]];
   adjk = (Unitize@(# + Transpose@#) & /@ 
      Flatten[Flatten[Outer[ReplacePart[#1, 1->#2]&, {#}, filtPerms[#,rows],  1], 1] & /@ skels, 1]);
   gathered = GatherBy[adjk, Total[Flatten[#]] &];
   Flatten[DeleteDuplicates[#, IsomorphicGraphQ[AdjacencyGraph@#1, AdjacencyGraph@#2] &] & /@ 
     gathered, 1]]

GraphicsGrid@Partition[Framed /@ AdjacencyGraph /@ getConnG@6, 8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I modified your code slightly so that `getConnG[6]` runs in 5 seconds as opposed to 30 seconds on my machine. The major point is that `DeleteDuplicates` has quadratic time complexity when using a user defined comparison function. Thus, breaking the list of graphs in smaller parts using the total number of edges helps a lot. Of course, `DeleteDuplicates` can run like $n\log(n)$, when the data is linearly ordered, but that's not generally possible with a user defined comparison function.

Comment: `getConnG[7]` in about 6 minutes.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thanks! Sound good, very clever. I'm trying to filter the `rows` to use on each `getConnF[n-1]` based on the `Automorphisms[]` of the `getConnF[n-1]` and its permutation group to produce much less isomorphic results to be discarded later.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I've done it. Resulted in a 40% time gain.

Comment: Should be faster if you use FindIsomorphism[g,g,All] on a Graph object. On my iPhone right now so I can't try it just now.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I don't have v10 :(

Answer (score 7):

The [`geng` tool](https://www.mankier.com/1/nauty-geng) of the [nauty suite](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) can generate all non-isomorphic connected graphs on a specified number of vertices.  The format used by nauty is directly supported by Mathematica, making it easy to use these tools.

I installed nauty using MacPorts (`sudo port install nauty`), but it's generally easy to compile on Unix-like systems.  Once you have the `geng` binary, simply use the command below (adjusting the path to `geng` appropriately).

```
cg = Import["!/opt/local/bin/geng -c 9", "Graph6"];

Length[cg]    
(* 261080 *)
```

(This takes a minute or so.)

As you can see, there are 261,080 connected non-isomorphic graphs on 9 vertices.

If you want even larger graphs, it will be useful to read them one-by-one. You can do it like so:

```
geng = StartProcess[{"/opt/local/bin/geng", "-c", "9"}]
Import[geng, {"Graph6", "GraphList", 123}] (* read 123th graph from the output *)
```

---

**Original answer:**

The website http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html contains a list of *all* unlabelled graphs, with up to 10 vertices.

**Update:** As @paw says in a comment, the format used on this website can be read directly by Mathematica, so the conversion I described below is not necessary: [Graph6](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Graph6.html).

---

It uses a special format, which can be converted to an adjacency matrix using the `showg` program, downloadable (as C source code) from [here](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/formats.html).

Once converted to an adjacency matrix, Mathematica can read it.

---

I compiled `showg` on a Unix-like system with the command

```
cc -O2 showg.c -o showg
```

then imported e.g. the graph `H???C@w` to Mathematica using

```
First@ImportString[#, "Table"] & /@ Rest@Import["!echo H???C@w | ~/test/showg -A", "Lines"]
```

(I'm sure this can be done better...)

Comment: Yes this can be done better. Mathematica supports .g6 natively and you can import the list of graphs with n vertices with `gSet[n_] := Import["http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graph" <> ToString@n <> ".g6"];`

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a connected random graph with the same number of vertices and edges as g1.

```
adjm = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1,
     0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0,
     0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}};

g1 = AdjacencyGraph[adjm];
vc = VertexCount[g1];
ec = EdgeCount[g1];

rg := RandomGraph[{vc, ec}];

gr = rg; While[! ConnectedGraphQ[gr], gr = rg]; gr
```

[image]