# Find all connected undirected graphs with n edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to find the undirected connected graph with all 12 edges, corresponding to https://oeis.org/A002905.

I searched for this answer [enumerating-all-connected-graphs-with-9-vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60696/enumerating-all-connected-graphs-with-9-vertices), which can give small-scale results.

```
allEdges[n_] := Flatten[Table[UndirectedEdge[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, i + 1, n}]];
allConnected[n_] := Select[Map[Graph[Range[n], #, VertexLabels -> Automatic]&, Subsets[allEdges[n]]], ConnectedGraphQ];
allConnectedEdge[rank_, edge_] := DeleteDuplicatesBy[Select[allConnected[rank], EdgeCount@# == edge &], CanonicalGraph];

g6 = Flatten@Table[allConnectedEdge[i, 6], {i, 1, 7}]
g6 // Length
```

But it is very slow to generate according to the vertices, because the connected graph of given edges is much sparser than that of given vertices.

Is there a better way to generate it?

Comment: The numbers in OEIS are unclear to me. The command of Maple 2023 for numbers of non-isomorphic undiredted graphs with `k` vertices and `12` edges `for k from 6 to 15 do
    [GraphTheory:-NonIsomorphicGraphs(k, 12), GraphTheory:-NonIsomorphicGraphs(k, 12, restrictto = connected)];
end do` results in `[5, 5] [131, 126] [1312, 1169] [5995, 4495] [15772, 8548][28259, 8833] [39243, 5026] [46415, 1301] [50159, 0][51814, 0]`.

Comment: I suggest using `geng` for all vertex counts up to `edgeCount+1`. Use `-c` for connected and fix the number of edges. I mentioned `geng` in a few answer here. Sorry, no time to write up an answer now, but let me know if you can't get this working.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's out of memory, I downloaded the results from http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html